# Repetir una funcion de busqueda varias veces e imprimir el tiempo

Tags: python-3.x, timer

Auxilio!
Queria perdir ayuda con el siguiente código de python, son tres funciones de busqueda (secuencial, binaria y binaria recursiva, y me piden con la funcion timer calcular el tiempo que tarda cada una, pero debe ser 20 veces, y ahí esta mi complicacion, porque no se donde agregar el ciclo for o while para que se repitta 20 veces, y poder imprimir los tiempos

```
import random

    lista=[]
    
    for i in range(1,100):
        lista.append(random.randint(1,10000))
        lista.sort()
       
    print(lista)
    
    
    print("Numero Buscado aleatorio")
    
    aleatorio=random.randint(1,1000)
    
    print(aleatorio)
    
    
       
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
    
    
    
    inicio= timer()
    
    #bsecuencial: int->str
    #dado un numero generado aleatoriamente entre 1 y 1000 lo busca en una lista de 100
    #que tiene elementos del 1 al 10000 realizando comparaciones.
    #Ejemplo: aleatorio=100001 entrega false.
                 
    def bsecuencial(lista,aleatorio):
        indice=0
        encontradolista_aleatorio=False
        detenerse=False
    
        while indice < len(lista) and not encontradolista_aleatorio and not detenerse:
            if lista[indice]==aleatorio:
                encontradolista_aleatorio=True
    
            else:
                if lista[indice]>aleatorio:
                    detenerse=True
                else:
                   indice=indice+1
    
        return encontradolista_aleatorio
        detenerse=False
        if encontradolista_aleatorio<20:
            detenerse=False
        else:
            encontradolista_aleatorio==20
            detenerse=True
    
    
    fin=timer()
    
    print("Tiempo de busqueda secuencial")
    print(fin-inicio)
    
    #bbinaria: int->str
    #realiza una busqueda comparndo con el elemento central de una lista
    #dividiendo la lista en partes pequeñas
    
    def bbinaria(lista,aleatorio):
        inicio=0
        fin=len(lista)-1
        encontradolista_aleatorio=False
    
        while inicio<=fin and not encontradolista_aleatorio:
            media=(inicio+fin)//2
            if lista[media]==aleatorio:
                encontradolista_aleatorio=True
            else:
                if aleatorio<lista[media]:
                    fin=media-1
                else:
                    inicio=media+1
        return encontradolista_aleatorio
               
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
    
    print("Tiempo de busqueda binaria")
    
    inicio=timer()
    bbinaria(lista,aleatorio)
    fin=timer()
    demora=fin-inicio
    print(demora)
    
    #brecursiva:int->str
    #brecursiva: reduce en cada iteracion el ambito de busqueda a la mitad
    #basandose en comparaciones con el elemento central del intervalo
    #Ejemplo: dado un numero generado aleatoriamente 10002, entrega false.
    
    
    def brecursiva(lista,aleatorio):
        if len(lista)==0:
            return False
        else:
            media=len(lista)//2
            if lista[media]==aleatorio:
                return True
            else:
                if aleatorio<lista[media]:
                   return brecursiva(lista[:media],aleatorio)
                else:
                   return brecursiva(lista[media+1:],aleatorio)
    
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
    
    print("Tiempo de busqueda recursiva")
    
    inicio=timer()
    brecursiva(lista,aleatorio)
    fin=timer()
    print(fin-inicio)
```

es un poco largo jajaj, pero queria preguntarles si alguien sabe como hacer que se repita 20 veces la funcion. La idea es medir el tiempo que demora cada tipo de busqueda, para lo cual tengo que obtener 20 mediciones de cada una e imprimirlas. Lo intente con un ciclo for pero no se por qué me arroja un error cada vez que lo ejecuto.
alguien me podia ayudar? que esten bien!

---

y en caso de que se quisiera medir e imprimir cuanto se demora en ejecutar una vez la función pero 20 tiempos diferentes,(20 para bsecuencial, 20 para bbinaria y 20 para brecursiva), como podria implementar el ciclo for dentro del codigo?

Comment: Lo que queres es ejecutar 20 veces una funcion y saber cuanto demoró en hacerlo?

Comment: el objetivo es imprimir la cantidad de tiempo que la funcion tarda en encontrar un numero aleatorio diferente, 20 veces, e imprimirlos por separado (20 filas), por eso estoy complicado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es bastante compacto, si defines un diccionario con las funciones que quieres verificar y luego recorres el mismo y por cada función repites un ciclo las `veces` que quieras

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

funciones = {"bsecuencial": bsecuencial,
             "bbinaria": bbinaria,
             "brecursiva": brecursiva}

veces = 20
for nombre, funcion in funciones.items():
  inicio=timer()

  for vez in range(1,veces+1):
    funcion(lista,aleatorio)
  
  fin=timer()
  print("{0}: {1})".format(nombre, fin-inicio))
```

Pero por cierto, esto que buscas hacer, es lo que de hecho realiza el módulo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html)

Answer (score 1):

Para poder ejecutar una funcion varias veces lo que tienes que hacer es usar un bucle for cuando llames a la función, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
for i in range(20): #Ejecuta la funcion bsecuencial 20 veces
    bsecuencial(lista,aleatorio)
```

Ahora, tu tambien quieres saber cuanto demora la computadora en ejecutar esa funcion 20 veces, por lo que tendras que hacer uso de la libreria time

```
import time

inicio = time.perf_counter() # time.perf_counter = default_timer()

for i in range(20):
    bsecuencial(lista,aleatorio)

fin = time.perf_counter
```

En la variable `inicio` se guarda el tiempo que demoro la computadora en llegar a leer esa linea, y en la variable `fin` lo mismo, entonces al hacer la resta te da el tiempo total que demoro en ejecutar la funcion 20 veces (Notese que `inicio` esta declarado antes que ingrese al bucle).

Este código puede que te sirva como ejemplo mas facil:

```
import time

def Foo(x):
    x+=10
    return x

Suma = 0
inicio = time.perf_counter()

for i in range(20):
    Suma = Foo(Suma)
    time.sleep(1)

fin = time.perf_counter()

print("Se ejecuto la funcion 20 veces en: ",fin-inicio,"segundos")
print("La suma es:",Suma)
```

time.sleep(1) para el programa por 1 segundo, esto lo hice para que puedas ver que funciona correctamente. Si ejecutas el programa el tiempo que demora es 20 segundos con algunas milesimas de segundo.